# Changing permissions for file on Windows machine from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, scp

I have currently got a PHP script running on a Debian machine to export SQL tables to csv files and then connect to and save on a Windows PC.

I would like to also be able to change the permissions to be read only once it is on that PC, however I would like the Debian root user to still have write access to be able to edit and overwrite the file as necessary.

Is it possible to change Windows permissions from linux? How would I achieve this if so?

Thanks!

Comment: Debian doesn't respect NTFS file permissions.  So any users on Debian would have access to this file.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, setting Windows disk-permissions by a Linux computer 
over the network is not possible.
You will need to set the permissions manually on the Windows side.

You could create a Windows account that has those permissions on the folder,
share the folder, and let smbclient use the user-name and password when
connecting, so the permissions are inherent in the account that is used.